# Compiling a file with repetition of the same document

Tags: formatting, numbering, pdf

What I am trying to do is to implement an option on my tex file that allows me to choose how many times the document I wrote is repeated in the compiled pdf. The reason is that I need the pages to preserve a *continuous numbering* rather than just being duplicated.

At the moment, what I do write my test.tex and then aside a test-many.tex file that copies test.tex as many times as I need using the input command. This means that I also have to comment out the begin/end document in test.tex which makes the whole procedure a bit messy. I am sure there is a better way to implement this and that here is the place to ask!

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

My example test.tex:

```
%\documentclass[]{article} 

%\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{0}

{\huge{The task}}

\section{A sample section}

We want to create a pdf file with the pages of this document repeated for a predefined number of times, using \emph{continuous page numbering}. 

%\end{document}
```

My example test-many.tex

```
\documentclass[]{article} \begin{document}  

\input{test.tex} \cleardoublepage

\input{test.tex} \cleardoublepage

\input{test.tex} \cleardoublepage

\input{test.tex} \cleardoublepage


\end{document}
```

And the desired result (only second page for the sake of space)[image]:

Comment: Please use code format (`{}` or ctrl+k ) rather than quotation format for code. If you use something like `standalone` you can avoid needing to comment out the class etc. Or you could use a loop.

Comment: thank you but I am looking for away to have such a functionality without needing a second tex file. Because most of the time I am editing test.tex and then I always have to comment out begin-end document and compile the test-many.tex...

Comment: One of my suggestions would avoid the need for the second file and the other would avoid the need to comment anything out. That was the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like cfr suggested you could use a for-loop to get the desired result. Your main document could then look something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{forloop}
\def\howOften{6}

\begin{document}  

\newcounter{k}
\forloop{k}{1}{\value{k} < \howOften}
{
\setcounter{section}{0}

{\huge{The task}}

\section{A sample section}

We want to create a pdf file with the pages of this document repeated for a predefined number of times, using \emph{continuous page numbering}. 

\cleardoublepage
}

\end{document}
```

How many times the document should be repeated can be said by changing the 6 into whatever number is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this still requires two separate tex files right? I was wondering if there is a way to structure this within a single tex file with the option on the number of times at the beginning. Is this possible?

Comment: @Dimitris You can put whatever you like in place of the `\input...` line.

Comment: Modified the code, though I don't know if that's what you Need?

Comment: Embarrassingly enough yes ;) Thanks for the tip. For the sake of completeness, I'd put for {k}{0} so that 1 means print the pdf once.